# When is an exact 2-form harmonic?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $\alpha$ be an exact two-form, $\alpha=d\beta$ for some one-form $\beta$, when is $\alpha$ harmonic? By uniqueness of harmonic forms in cohomology classes, it cannot be harmonic?

Comment: To put it another way, $\text{im} d$ is $L^2$-orthogonal to $\ker d^\ast$, so a form in both must be zero (harmonic forms are in $\ker d \cap \ker d^\ast$). Also, this may be implicit in your question, but you need to assume the manifold is compact to apply the usual Hodge theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you answered your own question. If $\alpha=d\beta$, it is zero in cohomology, but harmonic forms represent nontrivial cohomology classes. Like you said, you can see this by uniqueness, since the 0 form also represents $0$ in cohomology.

Comment: Excuse me, may I ask another question? Let $(M^4,g)$ be a Riemannian four-manifold with $b_2^+>0$ and $b_2^->0$, is it possible to find two harmonic two-forms $\alpha\in H^2_+(M)$ and $\beta\in H^2_-(M)$ such that \begin{equation*} |\alpha(x)|^2=|\beta(x)|^2\quad \text{for all } x\in M? \end{equation*}

Comment: @user38600: I think you should ask that as a separate question on the site. I don't know the answer off the top of my head.